# Can React 18 work well with react-redux and react-router?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-router

My current react application has the following versions:

```
react 17.0.x
react-dom 17.0.x
react-redux 7.2.x
react-router-dom 5.x.x
react-scripts 4.0.x
redux 4.x.x
```

So my first step to upgrade to `react@18` was to update `react-scripts` to `5.0`, I then updated `react` and `react-dom` to 18.x (also the @types for each).

Now my main entry file looks like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
 document.getElementbyId("root")
);
```

This then loads my `<App />` which looks like:

```
const App = () => {
  <ConfigureProvider ... >
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Switch> 
        <Router ... />
      </Switch>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </ConfigureProvider>
}
...
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

I know I have to change this to use `createRoot`, but does `createRoot` support me passing in a `Provider` from `react-redux`?

Can I continue this upgrade and still use `react-redux`, `redux` and `react-router-dom` or are any of these libraries just not compatible anymore with React 18?  I'm not sure how to setup the `Provider`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I have to change this to use `createRoot`, but does
> `createRoot` support me passing in a `Provider` from `react-redux`?

React 18 didn't change how JSX works, just render the redux `Provider` component where you need it, e.g. wrapping the `App` component.

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import * as ReactDOMClient from "react-dom/client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import App from "./App";
import store from "./store";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

> Can I continue this upgrade and still use `react-redux`, `redux` and
> `react-router-dom` or are any of these libraries just not compatible
> anymore with React 18?

Yes, you can continue the upgrade and use `react-redux`/`redux`, though the current recommendation is to install and use [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) (`@reduxjs/toolkit`) as it ***majorly*** cuts down on the amount of boilerplate code you need to handwrite yourself (*IDK, at least 50%, maybe more*).

Only React 18 and pre-v5.3.3 versions of `react-router-dom` will have problems, and ***only if*** you are rendering the app into React's `StrictMode` component (*which you should be*). See my answer [here](/a/71833424/8690857) regarding the issue and solution. This is a non-issue in `react-router-dom@5.3.3` and beyond.

If you go on to upgrade `react-router-dom` from v5 to v6 you're going to have a fun ride.  RRDv6 introduced *many* breaking changes and new router/routing patterns. Make sure to take a good read through both the [Overview](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview) and [Upgrading from v5 guide](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) to see what will likely be some fundamentally radical changes if you haven't already been introduced to v6. It's nothing too difficult, but speaking from experience I had to "unlearn" a lot of RRDv5 habits and concepts.

Comment: moving to redux toolkit might be a huge refactoring..not ready for that just yet!   I might not upgrade react-router-dom to v6 then since I want to get to a stable state first, thanks!

Comment: so the latest v5 will work with react 18?

Comment: @Blankman Yes, `react-router-dom@5` latest works well with `react@18`.

Comment: @Blankman If you are already fairly familiar with React and Redux then jumping to `redux-toolkit` was more like hopping over a crack in a sidewalk. It was about a 10-15 minute integration the first time I "migrated" a project, and only because I took it slowly, step-by-step, through the docs. It was painless. You really only need to swap out the older `createStore` function for the easier to use `configureStore` RTK function, all the existing actions/reducers work the same, and you update the legacy redux code to current redux code at your leisure.